# mongodb find multiple words in a string

Tags: mongodb, search, text, contains

I'm trying to find multiple words in a search string.

For example if I have to find a record that the message contains words: "first" and "second":

```
 { _id: 1, message: "first and second word" },
 { _id: 2, message: "first only" },
 { _id: 3, message: "second only" },
 { _id: 4, message: "second and first" }
```

It should returns:

```
{ _id: 1, message: "first and second word" },
{ _id: 4, message: "second and first" }
```

I tried:

> db.messages.find({
> $text: {$search: "second first"}
> })

But it works like an OR, returns records that contains only one word.

how could I achieve this in Mongo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
db.messages.find("text", {search:"\"second\" \"first\""})
```

mongo docs [text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#phrases)